# IOException occurred ReadtoEnd vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exception, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I get this problem when i start my program with HttpWebRequest and proxies , please help

here is my code:

```
                Using response = req.GetResponse()
                    If response.ContentLength <> 0 Then
                        Using stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                            Dim page_code_1 As String = ""
                            Using reader = New StreamReader(stream)
                                page_code_1 = reader.ReadToEnd
                                reader.Close()
                                reader.Dispose()
                                stream.Close()
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End If
                End Using
```

Comment: post the stack trace, all of it

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is when i run this code some time its give me error of IOException occurred here is screenshot
![Image](http://s32.postimg.org/oc2m0syyt/Untitled22.png)

also this problem is only when i use some proxies